# Issue with Closing Keyboard and Unfocusing TextField in Bottom Sheet When Back Button is Pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing an issue in my Flutter app where I have a bottom sheet with a TextField. When the back button is pressed, I want to close the keyboard and unfocus the TextField. However, the TextField remains focused, even after the keyboard close. I have tried various solutions, including using WillPopScope, but none of them work as expected. How can I properly close the keyboard and unfocus the TextField when the back button is pressed within the bottom sheet?

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setModalState) {
      return OnBackPressed(
        perform: () {
          print('The back button on the device was pressed');
          _focusNode.unfocus();
        },
        child: Container(
          // Bottom sheet content
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Add comments...',
            ),
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            onEditingComplete: () async {
              _focusNode.unfocus();
              // Additional logic after editing is complete
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned the code and its worked normally:

```
                            showModalBottomSheet(
                                context: context,
                                isScrollControlled: true,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return const SizedBox(
                                    height: 500,
                                    child: TextField(
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: 'Add comments...',
                                      ),
                                      textInputAction: 
                                    TextInputAction.done,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              );
```

when I press the back button the keyboard disappears and the textfield become unfocused
can you bring me the complete code or file?

Comment: I know the keyboard disapears but i used the focusNode to manipulate the ui. if it has focus then a widget is not visible and if it doesn't then the widget be visible. i used the focusNode to handle that and when the back button is pressed iwhile the keyboard is open it doesn't do any actions. that's my problem